# getting null value on var_dump(getRecommendation($matrix,$getName));

Tags: php

**I am getting null value for function getRecommendation($matrix,$getName), the data obtained are working fine**
*still learining php*

```
<?php 
require('connection.inc.php');
require('recommend.php');

$userID=$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
$reco=mysqli_query($con,"select userrating.*,product.id,product.productName from userrating,product where userrating.userID='$userID' and product.id=userrating.productID");
$matrix=array();

    while($rec=mysqli_fetch_array($reco))
    {

        $users=mysqli_query($con,"select users.name from users where users.id=$rec[userID]");
        $username=mysqli_fetch_array($users);

        $matrix[$username['name']][$rec['productName']]=$rec['rating'];
        $getName= $username['name'];

    }
    var_dump(getRecommendation($matrix,$getName));
?>
```

**Here is the function code as well, it is for a recommendor system , fur now i jst need this code not to return null value**
         $value)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($key,$matrix[$product2]))
            {
                $similar[$key]=1;
            }

```
    }
        if($similar==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    foreach($matrix[$product1] as $key=>$value)
    {

        if(array_key_exists($key,$matrix[$product2]))
        {
            $sum=$sum+pow($value - $matrix[$product2][$key],2);
        }
    }
    return 1/(1+sqrt($sum));

}

function getRecommendation($matrix,$prod)
{
    foreach($matrix as $otherProduct=>$value)
    {
        if($otherProduct!=$prod){
            $sim=similarityDistance($matrix,$prod,$otherProduct);
            var_dump($sim);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show the `similarityDistance` function as well

Comment: Your queries should be parameterized. You are open to SQL injections. Additionally you should use `join` and `on` in your SQL not comma delimited `join` and using `where` for joining constraints.

Comment: Thank you sir I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually *return something from the function* `getRecommendation`. (That's why you get **NULL** now. The functions isn't returning anything).

```
function getRecommendation($matrix,$prod)
{
    foreach($matrix as $otherProduct=>$value)
    {
        if($otherProduct!=$prod){
            $sim=similarityDistance($matrix,$prod,$otherProduct);
            var_dump($sim);
        }
    }

   //I don't what you want to return. Maybe this, but it has to be something..
   return $sim; 
}
```

Comment: Tried it still getting null

Comment: What happens if you change return $sim to return 'hello'; ?

Comment: When I return $sim as you placed up , It doesn't recognize it. And yes it returns hello when placed in place of sim, in place of sim you've instructed to return

Comment: Says undefined variable if I return sim as you instructed

Comment: Yes but what happens if you replace $sim with the string 'hello' ?

Comment: I get returned hello

Comment: Yes and there you have it. You have to return something. When you had return $sim ; you return nothing because $sim was not set to any value in the function.